# How to display files from a mysql database as anchor links to a python flask framework using mysql.connector

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

I am unable to display my files on my flask web application because of an anonymous error you can check the code :

```
@app.route("/ImageUpload", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def ImageUpload():
    if is_authenticated():
        googleAccountName = session['name']
        response = requests.get(f'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/{session["google_id"]}?personFields=photos&key={api_key}')
        profile_pic_url = response.json()['photos'][0]['url']
        
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # Get the selected unit
            selected_unit = request.form['Units']
            
            # Check if any files were uploaded
            if 'files[]' not in request.files:
                flash('No file uploaded')
                return redirect(request.url)
                
            files = request.files.getlist('files[]')
            
            # Check if any files were uploaded
            if not files:
                flash('No file uploaded')
                return redirect(request.url)
            
            # Check if any file is of invalid type
            allowed_extensions = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'pdf'])
            for file in files:
                if file.filename.split('.')[-1] not in allowed_extensions:
                    flash('Invalid file type: ' + file.filename)
                    return redirect(request.url)
                
            # Save the files to the database
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            for file in files:
                sql = "INSERT INTO ImageAndWord (Unit, File_Type, File) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
                val = (selected_unit, file.filename.split('.')[-1], file.read())
                mycursor.execute(sql, val)
                mydb.commit()

            flash('Files uploaded successfully!')
            return redirect(request.url)
    
    return render_template("Imageupload1.html", googleAccname=googleAccountName, profile_pic=profile_pic_url)
```

the html code  :

```
            {{% for file in allFiles %}}
            <a href="{{ file }}">{{ fileCount }}</a>
            {{%endfor%}}
```

I was expecting the files to display but the files only download to the database without actually displaying on the html website

Answer (score 0):

Snice you want to display the file, you should upload/save the file itself into a folder, remember the folder must be inside static

```
import os
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = '/path/to/the/uploads'
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = {'txt', 'pdf', 'png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'}

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

Comment: But I want to get the info from a mysql database